# A rails migration that specifies the distance between two months..?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, sqlite

I would like to make two drop downs. a start time, and an end time. Specifically, I only need months. I would like to, for example, choose January, and then March, and then have the database read that it is the these two months plus February.

Is there any out of the box migration that could work?

I'm guessing..

script/generate migration AddMonthsToClass beginDate:datetime #through endDate:datetime

I apologize ahead of time if my question sounds retarded! Sorry! :D

Comment: Apology accepted ;) 

There is no out of the box migration that comes close. Please specify if you want to add DB columns, records or just somehow track time data for another model?

Comment: Not entirely sure of those three. My objective is to allow a user to choose two different months, and the database would read a span of months inbetween as well. So (now i'm text-brain-storming), maybe it would be best to just create an array of months. And the selection of two months, also selects those that inbetween. Ah..anything out of the box for that ? :D

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Save the months in a db column? I didn't understand it very well :/

Comment: I need to save an array. So let's say I choose my start month as "January", and my end month as "April", then I would be Rails to input into the database the months of "January, February, March, and April".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you: http://www.francisfish.com/getting_the_number_of_months_between_two_dates_in_rubyrails.htm

After you get the number of months, you can get the month names from this:

```
months = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
months[start_date.month, number_of_months]
```

eg
months[Time.now.month, 5]
=> ["May", "June", "July", "August", "September"]

edit:
Instead of that, you can use:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES[start_date.month, number_of_months]
```

edit:
Or if you get the month numbers in your select tag, you can just use:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES[start_month_num, end_month_num]
```

but, this would fail if end_month_num is less than start_month_num

This should work:

```
if start_month <= end_month
  Date::MONTHNAMES[start_month..end_month]
else
  Date::MONTHNAMES[end_month..12] + Date::MONTHNAMES[1..start_month]
end
```